# Idiomatic Way to Insert/Upsert Protobuf Into A Relational Database

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, protocol-buffers

I have an Python object which is a ProtoBuf message, that I want to insert into a database.

Ideally I'd like to be able to do something like

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper, sessionmaker

from event_pb2 import Event

engine = create_engine(...)

metadata = MetaData(engine)

table = Table("events", metadata, autoload=True)

mapping = mapper(Event, table)

Session = sessionmaker(engine)
session = Session()

byte_string = b'.....'
event = Event()
event.ParseFromString(byte_string)

session.add(event)
```

When I try the above I get an error `AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'` when I try to create the `Event` object. Which isn't shocking because the `Event` class has been generated by ProtoBuf.

Is there a better i.e. safer or more succinct way to do that than manually generating the insert statement by looping over all the field names and values? I'm not married to using SqlAlchemy if there's a better way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's generally advised that you should limit protobuf generated classes to the client and server side gRPC methods and, for any uses beyond that, map Protobuf objects from|to application specific classes.

In this case, define a set of SQLAlchemy classes and transform the gRPC objects into SQLAlchemy specific classes for your app.

This avoids breakage if e.g. gRPC maintainers change the implementation in a way that would break SQLAlchemy, it provides you with a means to translate between e.g. proto Timestamps and your preferred database time format, and it provides a level of abstraction between gRPC and SQLAlchemy that affords you more flexibility in making changes to one or the other.

There do appear to be some tools to help with the translation but, these highlight issues with their approach e.g. [Mercator](https://mercator.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sqlalchemy-orm-support.html).